# LiDAR first and last returns eCognition

Tags: lidar, ecognition

Recently I downloaded the new version of eCognition Developer. Earlier in LiDAR data processing using algorithms, it was pretty easy to generate LiDAR first and last returns.

Before, when you chose the algorithm "LiDAR File Converter" there were options under the Converter Parameters such as "Convert Parameter" and "Returns". By setting the parameter "Returns", I could create two new image layers, i.e., LiDAR first and last returns.

Now with the new version, I don't know how to do that because there's no "Return" parameter listed anymore. I couldn't find any instructions either. How do I generate LiDAR's first and last returns in eCognition?

Comment: Before when you chose the algorithm "LiDAR File Converter" there were options under the Converter Parameters such as Convert Parameter and Returns. For the former it was possible to choose Intensity and for the later it was possible to choose Last or First.

Comment: Tks for the update. What version of eCognition you are talking about? While we can guess it is the newest release today, with time (and with other releases) we won't be able to know which version you are referring to. The 'new images' you talk about are just the point clouds filtered by return, or are rasters processed from point clouds with such returns (for example DEM and DSM)? Please, edit the question. Also, can you add a screenshot showing the dialog where you see the features are missing?